# Clearing doubts about height: auto css property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know that the `height: auto` property sets the height depending upon its content's height. Currently my div has a background image. This div is part of a CSS grid whose width is dynamic (like 90% of the parent's width) and I am fixing the background-image with `background-size: contain` and `background-position: center`.

So when I reduce the device width the image gets reduced along width and height due to setting the grid width to be dynamic, but the div's height doesn't get reduced. That's why I am trying to give that div a height of auto so the div's height will depend upon the background images height.

Still, the background-image's height is getting reduced when I reduce the device width, but the div which holds the background-image that's height isn't getting reduced, so the overall grid's height is not reducing and my image with the grid looks ugly.

Does background-image count as content of a div? If not, then how should I reduce the div's height corresponding to the background-image's height reduction upon the device width reduction so I can use fit-content for my grid rows?

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
 <div class='first-content image-postion'></div>
 <div class='second-content image-position'></div>
 <div class='third-content image-position'></div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper{
 display: grid;
  width: 85%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, fit-content(100px));
  grid-template-areas:
    "first second"
    "third second";
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.first-content {
  background-image: url('');
  grid-area: first;
}
.second-overview {
   background-image: url('');
  grid-area: third;
}
.third-overview {
   background-image: url('');
  grid-area: second;
}
.image-position {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: if you set a background image via CSS then no, it does not count as content and does not contribute to the div's dimensions. You have to manually set their height with css.

Comment: your div height is defined by `grid-template-rows: repeat(2, fit-content(100px));`

Comment: but with the help of fit-content i am not setting the rows height to dependable upon it's inner div's height but the maximum height should be 100px

Comment: *I am trying to give that div a height of auto so the div's height will depend upon the background images height* the background-image does not create any height whatsoever by itself.